# grep -z: why \0 produces no results?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Scenario:

```
$ cat t0.txt
xxx
yyy

$ man grep | grep '\-\-null\-data' -A1
       -z, --null-data
              Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.

$ grep -Pzo 'xxx\0yyy' t0.txt
<nothing>

$ grep -Pzo 'xxx\nyyy' t0.txt
xxx
yyy
```

So, if grep "treats the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte", then why `'xxx\0yyy'` produces no results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` processes lines; by default these are separated by `\n`, and the `-z` option tells `grep` that it should instead use `\0` as the line separator.

`-z` *describes* the data given to `grep`; it doesn’t change the data being fed to `grep`. You’d use it with data really using `\0` as a separator, *e.g.* the output of `find -print0`.

Even if your input data did contain `\0`, you wouldn’t be able to `grep` for `\0` with the `-z` option: `grep` looks for matches inside lines, so it can’t match the line separator. Your `\n` pattern works because your input contains that *and* `grep` isn’t using `\n` as a line separator (because of the `-z` option).

Comment: Is there an option "... each terminated by an X byte", where `X` is user-defined?

Comment: I’m not aware of one.